# Nexus 7 not being picked up by adb (when I connect it to the laptop via usb)

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb, nexus-7

I run the command "adb devices" and it doesn't list the nexus 7 device even though the drivers are installed correctly.  The drivers show up as "Android Composite ADB Interface".  I have "USB Debugging" turned on in the nexus 7 device.  Also, I did already try to kill and restart the adb service without any luck.

When I connect my HTC One android device, however, it shows up when I run the command "adb devices" even if I don't have USB Debugging turned on.  The main difference in drivers is that the HTC One driver shows up as "Android ADB Interface" when I plug it in.  So, it doesn't have the "Composite" in the name.

Any advice on getting the Nexus 7 to show up when I run "adb devices" would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this, connect the device, then swipe down your notifications on the status bar (left side), tap on `Connected as a media device` and change that to `Camera (PTP)`.

Answer (score 4):

I set up my Nexus 7 as a test device recently, and this is the procedure that I followed:

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

When I plug my device in to the computer via USB it immediately shows up under the "devices" tab.

If you are certain that you have installed the correct driver
then please review the following steps from the above page:

> 2.Enable USB debugging on your device. ◦On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings >
>   Applications > Development. ◦On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in
>   Settings > Developer options.  Note: On Android 4.2 and newer,
>   Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to
>   Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the
>   previous screen to find Developer options.
>
> 3.Set up your system to detect your device. ◦If you're developing on Windows, you need to install a USB driver for adb. For an installation
>   guide and links to OEM drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.

Answer (score 0):

Try turn off the USB debugging option and turn it on again. If all else fail,reboot your tablet.

Comment: I turned the usb debugging off and on and tried rebooting, still same issue.